# Why this change to /etc/limits does not work

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, etc

I have made below changes to /etc/limits file for limiting the number of logins for a particular user from ssh.

```
rajan L2
```

rajan is username here.

After making these changes I logged out from session and logged in again so that effect of change should take place.

But can still log in through more 2 than shell using ssh protocol.

I also has tried setting `maxsession 2` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` but didn't work out.

Can any body tell me what I am doing wrong?

**Edit**: I want maximum number of simultaneous SSH sessions to 5.

Comment: What do you want to do? Can you edit your Question and explain it?

Comment: @kockiren I want maximum number of simultaneous SSH sessions to 5

Comment: What Distri you use? Which Version? Copy your sshd config

Comment: Not sure I can copy my sshd_config but I can tell you if any parameter is set or not .I am using linux kernel 3.4.2

Comment: What operating system are you using? If Linux, which distro? (And the `MaxSessions` option in sshd_config is not what you want.)

Comment: And what Distri? Debian, Centos, SUSE, RHEL ....

Comment: @JennyD I tried setting up MaxSessoins 5 in my sshd_config file but still can open from more than 5 ssh connection from different terminal.Is it the right way to test?

Comment: Did you restart sshd after changing the config?

Comment: Yes I did using /etc/init.d/sshd reload

Answer (score 2):

The `MaxSession` option in sshd_config is for the number of simultaneous sessions per connection, not the total number of connections.

I'd recommend using the PAM module `pam_limits` instead. On the CentOS server I happen to have handy, you would edit `/etc/security/limits.conf` to contain the line

```
rajan - maxlogins 2
```

to limit Rajan to two simultaneous logins. There's more information in `man limits.conf`.

Comment: I don't have pam.d installed on my machine and can't see /etc/security/limits.conf on my box.I have /etc/securetty on my box.